# Lua jump to right line

Tags: vim, lua

I have a makefile that looks like:

```
default:
  lua blah.lua
```

Now, in Vim, I type ":make".

There's an error in my Lua code; it gives a file name + line number. I would like Vim to jump to the right file/line. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the error-format string to recognise the lua interpreter's output. For example, add this to your .vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufRead *.lua setlocal efm=%s:\ %f:%l:%m
```

That assumes the errors in your version of Lua look like this:

```
lua: blah.lua:2: '=' expected near 'var'
```

Bonus tip: rather than use a makefile, you can use the `makeprg` setting:

```
autocmd BufRead *.lua setlocal makeprg=lua\ %
```

That will run the current file through lua when you type `:make`.

Comment: Nice. Thanks! I understand the %f:%l part. Care to explain how "%.%#" matches "lua" ?

Comment: `%.%#` is the error format equivalent to a `.*` in a regular regex. IOW it matches anything at all (e.g. /usr/bin/lua). Bit of a hack maybe, but gets the job done!

Comment: is there a way to make it say "lua: " instead of "%.%#" ? that seems more intuitive/clearer for me, but I don't know how to express taht in the error-format

Comment: I've changed the %.%# thing to just %s, which matches any string (RTFM FTW!), but to hardcode it for just lua, you'd use `autocmd BufRead *.lua setlocal efm=lua:\ %f:%l:%m`

Comment: @richq: Using %s instead of %.%# makes vim search for the captured string ("lua") instead of jumping to the line number. vimdoc says, "The "%s" conversion specifies the text to search for to locate the error line." Using `efm=%s:\ %f:%m` makes this more apparent because it shows the jump text in the line numbers spot. (vim 8.0.596 doesn't jump to the line number if that search text isn't found.)